# Wildcard file include in .NET Core project with F#

Tags: f#, .net-core

I was trying out ASP.NET Core with F# using the `aspnet` Yeoman template, and I found something I didn't expect in `project.json`:

```
"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true,
"debugType": "portable",
"compilerName": "fsc",
"compile": {
  "includeFiles": [
    "Controllers.fs",
    "Startup.fs",
    "Program.fs"
  ]
}
```

If I move any of the existing files, I get a build error. If I change the `includeFiles` property to a single string with the value `*.fs`, I get the following message:

> The 'includeFiles' property cannot contain wildcard characters.

The F# project templates from the `dotnet` CLI also include this structure in their `project.json`.

Having to add every single file to your `project.json` manually seems like a pretty big productivity impediment to using F# with .NET Core. Is there any way around this currently?

Comment: [`project.json` is going away pretty soon](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/), I would just suffer through it for a few months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In F# you have to explicitly define the order in which source files  are compiled.

So *wildcard* doesn't make sense in any F# build system.

A good blog post about [Organizing modules and files](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part3/)

Comment: I had no idea F# worked that way. Definitely a surprise coming from C#. Thanks!